# How can I add two images to this header?

Tags: html, css

I got a header that looks like this. Now I want to add to images to the right side of the header that will act as a contact and help link button.

How can I do this?

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #eee;
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #e3e3e3);
    width: 100%;
}

#header img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 142px;
    height: 12px;
}
```

and

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

Comment: `that will act as a contact and help link button.` what do you mean??

Comment: Looks like what?

Comment: Have a look at using flexbox, but this question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Answer (score 0):

if you want the second image to be right aligned.

I add a new `<img>` element below the original one and assign them both an id. Namely logo1 and logo2.

```css
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #eee;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #e3e3e3);
  width: 100%;
}

#header img,
#logo1 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 142px;
  height: 12px;
}

#header #logo2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img id="logo1" src="logo.png" alt="logo" />
  <img id="logo2" src="logo2.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..

```css
 .header
              {
                    position:absolute;
                    top:0px;
                    height:40px;
                    color:#333;
                    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #e3e3e3);
                    width:100%;
              }
              .logo {
                    float: left; 
              }
              
              .logo img {
                    margin-top: 14px;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    width: 142px;
                    height: 12px;
                   }
              
             .images{
                    float:right;
                    margin-top: 14px;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    width: 142px;
                    height: 12px;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
          <div class="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
          <div class="images"><img src="contact.png" alt="contact"><img src="help.png" alt="help"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well you want the image act as button mean the image be a link.

so wrap the image with `a` tag and set `href` to whereever you want to

```css
 #header
   {
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      height:40px;
      color:#eee;
      background: linear-gradient(#fff, #e3e3e3);
      width:100%;
}
 #header img {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 14px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   width: 142px;
   height: 12px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
   <a href="home"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
</div>
```